# how to pass bearer token into the URL section for resetting password in laravel-8?

Tags: php, laravel-8

i developed two API's one is for forgetPassword and another one is resetPassword (it accepts token in Authorization and verifies the header in that)in postman it's working i am able to update my password successfully [[like this i am passing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6fx7.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6fx7.png), when i connect frontend to backend i add some button inside notification,when i click on the button it's redirected to another page it's showing not found [[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0glF8.png)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0glF8.png) .how to pass the token to frontend url ,please help me to fix this issue..

`ResetPasswordNotification.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Lang;


class ResetPasswordNotification extends Notification
{
    use Queueable;

    public $token;


    /**
     * Create a new notification instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($token)
    {
        $this->token = $token;
    }

    /**
     * Get the notification's delivery channels.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['mail'];
    }

    /**
     * Get the mail representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
     */
    public function toMail($temp)
    {
        $url = url("http://localhost:8000/reset/$this->token");
        return (new MailMessage)
                    ->subject(Lang::get('Reset Password Link!'))
                    ->line(Lang::get('You are receiving this email because we received a request for password reset'))
                    ->line(Lang::get('Copy the token'))
                    ->with($this->token)
                    ->action('Reset Password',url($url))
                    ->line('If you did not request a password reset, no further action is required!');
                   
    }

    /**
     * Get the array representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            //
        ];
    }
}
```

`my urls`

```
http://localhost:8000/reset  -->this is for ui page url
http://localhost:8000/api/auth/resetPassword -->backend api url
```

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, you need to send the Authorization argument in the HTTP request header. In this case you will have to make an ajax call from your front-end to your back-end. Something like:

```
$('#some_button').on('click',function(){
    $.ajax({
          url: "your-backend-uri",
          type: 'POST',
          data: { 
              someKey: "some-value",
          },
          contentType: 'application/json',
          headers: {
              "Authorization": "Bearer " + your_token_here
          }
    });
});
```